# Need help parsing email body

Tags: apex-email-service, regular-expressions

I have an email service where clients can send me yes/no answers to questions I ask yet a lot of responses include narratives such as, "No, I do not like green eggs and ham," (and others).

Rather than bucketing responses other than just "yes" or "no" as invalid, what's a good approach to parsing a sentence looking for "yes" or "no" contained within the email body (including, "yes." and "no."?

The parts of the code that parses the email body for the single keyword I ask for is:

```
        string[] KeyWord = body.toLowerCase().split('\n');
        string command = KeyWord[0].trim();

        //Now just need to parse incoming email for real Email_for_Text_Messages__c and Id (enrollment ID in Subject line - maybe in parens)
        // Now process the incoming message body and do updates to DYGTJ
        command = command.toLowerCase();
        if (!part_list.isEmpty()) {
            if (command == 'y') {
                command = 'Yes';
                //smsHist.Responded__c=true;
            } else if (command == 'yes') {
                command = 'Yes';
                //smsHist.Responded__c=true;
            } else if (command == 'n') {
                command = 'No';
                //smsHist.Responded__c=true;
            } else if (command == 'no') {
                command = 'No';
                //smsHist.Responded__c=true;
            } else if (command == 'stop' || command == 'unsubscribe') {
                optout = true;
                command = 'Stop';
            } else {
                command = 'Invalid';
            }
        }
```

Comment: So you just want to catch Yes/No, or you want to figure out the whole sentence written in mail?

Comment: Einstein's Natural Language Processing might be an alternative here, but might also be overkill.

Comment: I looked at Einstein and that would be a good long-term solution. We are a nonprofit and do not have the license. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @MuzammilBajaria, Both would be ideal yet I think if I can reliably parse Yes/No at the beginning of a sentence or <space>yes/no<space> or even <space>y/n<period> I can adapt for common responses.

For example, I get a lot of "no. I did not" answers when I expect just yes or no.